# Make NuGet look for newer packages that satisfy wildcard

Tags: .net, nuget, csproj, nuget-package-restore

Using SDK-style csproj.

Scenario:

csproj:

```
<PackageReference Include="MyNamespace.Package" Version="3.5.4-*" />
<PackageReference Include="MyNamespace.Other" Version="3.5.3" />
```

Installed:

```
MyNamespace.Package 3.5.4-pre.1
MyNamespace.Other 3.5.3
```

In NuGet repo:

```
MyNamespace.Package 3.5.4-pre.1
MyNamespace.Package 3.5.4-pre.2
MyNamespace.Other 3.5.3
MyNamespace.Other 3.5.4
MyNamespace.Other 3.6.0
```

I *do not* want NuGet to modify any *PackageReference* entries.
I *do* want NuGet to install newest `MyNamespace.Package` that satisfies the wildcard, here it will be  `3.5.4-pre.2`.

Is there any built-in way to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

After writing the question I came up with another thing I have not tried.

To get it to look again in all the repos (or selected ones) and install according to the wildcard package resolution use command:

`nuget restore \Path\To\Solution.sln -NoCache [-Source \path\to\repo]`

`-NoCache` will make it ignore the "known" packages, but not *update* any of your references. It will find the newer package that satisfies the wildcard and install it.

Answer (score 3):

See floating versions here:
[NuGet PackageReference format - Floating Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files)

```
<ItemGroup>
<!-- ... -->
<PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Contoso.Utility.UsefulStuff" Version="3.6.0-beta*" />
<!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to do this with pre-release packages, but I believe that PackageReference and wildcards

```
<PackageReference Include="I.want.the.latest.version.of" Version="*" />
<PackageReference Include="I.want.the.latest.version.3.of" Version="3.*" />
```

along with msbuild /restore can achieve this. I'm doing the exact same thing in my project, where I want to consume the latest version of certain packages with each build, without modifying any PackageReference entries.

The msbuild /restore target supports a property called RestoreForce (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#restore-target) that has been very useful here.

NuGet.exe restore, as of this writing (version 5.4.0.6315) appears to have some bugs around supporting wildcard versions in PackageReference (https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8432). msbuild /restore does not suffer from those bugs.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019.